# Custom drush command not working

Tags: 7, drush

I have used [hook_drush_command](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!drush!docs!drush.api.php/function/hook_drush_command/7) to create a new drush command. This is my custom code for creating drush command.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_drush_command().
 */
function mymodule_drush_command() {
  $items = array();
  // Name of the drush command.
  $items['list-site-users'] = array(
    'description' => 'Print the list of users in the site',
    'callback' => 'drush_get_site_users',
  );
  return $items;
}

function drush_get_site_users() {
  $query = db_select('users', 'u');
  $query->fields('u', array('name'));
  $result = $query->execute();
  while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
       print_r($record['name']);
  }
}
```

After this I have exceuted `drush cc all` and `drush cc drush` for clearing drush. Then I have executed my custom drush command `drush list-site-users` command, but it is throwing the below error.

> The drush command 'list-site-users' could not be found.  Run `drush
>   cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have
>   installed new extensions.

My drush version is 5.10.0

Comment: This should go in the module_name.drush.inc file. In case someone is looking for a **Drupal 8** solution [this](https://github.com/npinos/drupal8-greenhouse/blob/master/content_types_greenhouse_job_post.drush.inc) is how I did it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_drush_command().
 */
function mymodule_drush_command() {
  $items['list-site-users'] = array(
    'description' => 'Does a database cleanup.',
    'examples' => array(
      'list-site-users' => 'Retrieve list for all users',
    ),
    'aliases' => array('lsu'),
  );
  return $items;
}

function drush_mymodule_list_site_users() {
  $query = db_select('users', 'u');
  $query->fields('u', array('name'));
  $result = $query->execute();
  while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
       print_r($record['name']);
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** Make sure you write the above code in `mymodule.drush.inc` file of any module.
Clear the cache and your drush command should work.

Comment: It works after placing in mymodule.drush.in file.
before I have plalced in my custom module

Comment: +1 for adding _mymodule_ in the callback name. It is important to avoid conflicts with other modules.

Answer (score 3):

I have made a mistake. For creating custom drush command we have to place code inside the `module.drush.inc`. I have placed the code inside my custom module. After placing the code inside `module.drush.inc` it works fine.