# Call to undefined function variable_get()

Tags: 7, drush

I have an ansible script that transfers a production database to my devel server, then runs a few Drush commands to prepare it (e.g. updating the filesystem settings, clearing the cache).

A more complex task is updating a nested configuration value like the following one.

```
mail_system:
  default-system: SmtpMailSystem
  maillog: MaillogMailSystem
```

Supposedly [I ought to be able to do this with `drush ev`](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/how-set-complex-string) (aka php-eval) and `variable_get()` and `variable_set()` as with `drush7 ev '$v = variable_get("file_public_path")'`, but I get this error message.

> Error: Call to undefined function variable_get() in /usr/local/bin/drush7.4.0/commands/core/core.drush.inc(1122): eval()'d code, line 1

It **does** work correctly when I use the interactive shell.

```
drush7 core-cli
self> variable_get('mail_system');
array:2 [
  "default-system" => "SmtpMailSystem"
  "maillog" => "MaillogMailSystem"
]
```

I can work-around it by reading the content of `$conf` easily enough.

```
drush7 ev 'global $conf; echo $conf["mail_system"]["default-system"];'
```

Writing involves a database query and clearly `variable_set()` is in core.

Why cannot I use `variable_get()` and `variable_set()`?

I am using Drush 7.4.0 and Drupal 7.59.

(I also have Drush 8.1.16 available, but that's much use for this, *Drush 8*'s cget and cset require *Drupal 8*, and *Drush 8* doesn't have *Drush 7*'s vget and vset.)

Comment: FWIW I just wrote a custom Drush command to do exactly what I wanted, this answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181848/custom-drush-command-not-working was useful for getting that working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are confusing Drush 8 and 9 - Drush 8 has `vget` and `vset`.

Using Drush 8, the following two commands worked:

```
drush vget "mail_system"

drush ev 'print_r(variable_get("mail_system"));'
```

PS! Drush 7 [isn't supported](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/) and you should use Drush 8 (currently 8.1.17) for Drupal 7.